How can I ensure there’s always a "full" constructor that includes all fields in certain classes?
I have a codebase where certain classes need to support a custom deep copy mechanism. To simplify this, I want to enforce that these classes always have at least one “full constructor” that takes and initializes every class field. While these classes might have multiple constructors (for convenience or partial initialization), I need a guaranteed constructor that includes all fields, enabling a reliable deep copy process.
I’m looking for ways to ensure that if someone adds a new field, they also update the “full constructor” to include that field.
For example, Let's say we have the following class:
public class User
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    
    public User(int id, string name)
    {
        id = id;
        name = name;
    }
}

If another developer added an address field to User but not to the constructor I want the code/build to break:
 public class User
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string address;

        public User(int id, string name)
        {
            id = id;
            name = name;
        }
    }


Preventing this at compile time probably needs a custom roslyn analyser. Other than that, this is more of a "human" problem. What kind of control do you have over "another developer"? If you don't have control over what they write, they can write anything the compiler accepts, and this is akin to asking "how do I stop someone from writing a class with exactly three fields". Can you for example, ask them to only declare records? Records already has a built-in deep copy mechanism.

Make a base class that contains all required fields and have only one ctor for it that contains all required fields?

If you want a copy, then you should use a so called copy constructor: public User (User original) { ... }. I also often use a Clone method based on MemberwiseClone() to not forget any field.

The code above is a very simplified situation. I want to enforce this on more than 20 classes, with 5-30 fields each. I know that this is a "human" problem and I'm sure that for now, I could keep it working by instructing the developers and doing code reviews. I'm looking for a solution for the long run. to prevent, let's a junior developer two years from now, breaking the expected behavior.

Regarding the MemberwiseClone(), we tried and it caused our CPU to spike

You could create a unit test for this, using reflection to test all the members against constructor parameters. Whilst developers would still be able to commit changes that break the expected behaviour, having a test in place should prevent such breakages getting committed to main development branch (that is, assuming you're using CI/CD to run the tests against each merge to your main code branch).

You can see the implementation of MemberwiseClone here in the Source Browser. It uses low-level memory copy functions and I would be very surprised if it wasn't very efficient.

"with 5-30 fields each." then you not only have a "are all fields named in the constructor" problem but also a "are they are used in the correct order" problem when cloning. There is nothing that prevents doing code reviews here.

MemberwiseClone won't do deep copies (that has been asked for) so you have to fight against it when using.

@Ralf, at least it copies all the value fields and immutable reference objects (like string) correctly. You will then have to do additional work on the other references.

When a new field is added, you (automatically) "re-generate" the "interface" for that class ... that is used by the "master initializer" / builder. The "master builder" will generate a compiler error if the new interface member is not implemented. Which implies using an Interface if you are not currently. The "contract".
